# Ignore spelling API in electron 8

Tags: electron

With the release of electron 8, I was implementing the newly released `spell check` API's on my electron app. The context menu should look similar to this:

[image: Conext menu for electron app]

I was able to implement `learn spelling` using [ses.addWordToSpellCheckerDictionary](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/all#sesaddwordtospellcheckerdictionaryword) API given in docs, however I am stuck trying to implement the `ignore spelling` part.

The difference between the two according to google is

**Ignore spelling**

> The word is ignored if it occurs again in the document (it will be highlighted in other documents)

**Learn Spelling**

> The word won't be flagged as misspelled in any document.

I can implement it such a way that the dictionary suggestions are not shown for a specific set of words stored in array, but that will still leave a red squiggly line below the word. Besides, there has to be a native API call implemented given spell check has been officially announced.

I could have simply used webFrame.setSpellCheckProvider, but then I would have to hard-code a language, add boilerplate code, use a node module.

Answer (score 0):

Try instead using [electron-spellchecker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@hfelix/electron-spellchecker) npm package:

It has an:

> Option to ignore a word at runtime only.